# ExtJS -- grid filters not working in 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

The grid filter is not showing up in the column header dropdown menu in Ext 4.2.2 and 4.2.3.

It works fine with 4.2.1

Here is the fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fck

Note the fiddle uses 4.2.1 (4.2.2 not available) and grid filters work just fine, but when I copied that code into my application the filter did not show up.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

thanks!

Comment: I think you need to require `Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter` as well.

Comment: that was it! no errors were thrown but requiring that class resolved the issue, thanks!

Comment: want to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the FiltersFeature class does not require its filter types that it uses, you'll have to require `Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter` as well.